# Outlook Add-ins installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, outlook

I developed outlook 2010 add-ins in VS2012. I publish with clickonce method with signing the vsto with sha256 RSA certificate.

It works fine for my developed machine but to other machine i got the error as :

Name: 
From: file:///F:/Hubnet Plugin/DISK1/DISK1/program files/Hubnet/HubnetOutlookPlugin.vsto

************** Exception Text **************
System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Exception reading manifest from file:///F:/Hubnet%20Plugin/DISK1/DISK1/program%20files/Hubnet/HubnetOutlookPlugin.vsto: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. ---> System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Manifest XML signature is not valid. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignedInfo(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignatureReturningKey(AsymmetricAlgorithm& signingKey)
   at System.Deployment.Internal.CodeSigning.SignedCmiManifest.Verify(CmiManifestVerifyFlags verifyFlags)
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream s)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream s)
   at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.GetManifests(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn().

Then i move my project to VS 2010 and publish it again works fine on developed machine but on other machine it goes inactive add-ins and on some machine it works fine.
I am stuck since few days.
I also try depoying the application using Shields installer method.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure that your client machine has Visual Studio 2010 Tools for office Runtime installed.

I solved by install this on client machine.

Comment: HI @Umar as you have worked on Microsoft add-ins, Could you please tell me the process how can i access flutter web app in outlook add-ins? (In Java script code)