# The manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened for some of the PC users but works fine for others

Tags: outlook, vsto, manifest, add-in, signing

The error happens when Outlook 2007 VSTO addin is loading at startup. This  Windows 7 PC is used by multiple domain users. The error happens only for some of those users. For other users the addin works fine. I assume the unfortunate users do not have some permissions but not sure to where to look at.

Please, help if you hit the same error in the past.  Thank you.

The error details are as follows

```
System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/<Application folder>/My_OutlookAddin.vsto: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. ---> System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Manifest XML signature is not valid. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied.
```

at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignedInfo(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignatureReturningKey(AsymmetricAlgorithm& signingKey)
   at System.Deployment.Internal.CodeSigning.SignedCmiManifest.Verify(CmiManifestVerifyFlags verifyFlags)
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream s)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream s)
   at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.GetManifests(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()

Comment: How was the add-in installed?  Was it by ClickOnce or MSI?  If MSI, was it installed at the machine-level (ie for all users)?

Comment: Thank you guys for your feedbacks. I have resolved the puzzle. Not entirely though.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for your feedbacks. I have resolved the puzzle. Firstly, the answers for your questions are as follows. The add-in was installed using setup.exe created in VS 2010 setup project, i.e. it was not a ClickOnce installation. The Visual Studio Tools for Office app was installed on the target PC and also was one of the prerequisites of the setup project. I believe the problem was caused by add-in project's signing certificate and strong name key (snk) file. The certificate was a temporary one issued by a developer. The snk file was created using this temporary certificate. I assume the generated add-in manifest worked only for a certain domain group users. I did not figure this out. What I did was I replaced the temporary certificate with the new one that company recently bought and created a new snk file. However, after deployment, add-in stopped working for all users. The error message was the same. That was when I started to look into the add-in manifest file. What I found was the manifest file created with new certificate had a SHA2 encryption algorithm. But, the VS 2010 can handle only earlier SHA1 version because the highest Framework version that it can target is FW 4. The SHA2 can be used only with FW 4.5 and higher  versions. The solution was to use a three years old SHA1 certificate and snk file that were used when the add-in was updated last time in 2013. I found them in the company source code repository. Even the certificate expired last year the add-in manifest still works. By the way, SHA1 encryption algorithm was deprecated from January 2016. Nowadays, all new certificates for signing application are issued with other algorithms like SHA2.

Answer (score 0):

Do the users it's not working for have Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) installed?

See this:

[Outlook Add-ins installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088414/outlook-add-ins-installation?rq=1)